# using pointer to work on single linked list

Tags: c++

This is a homework problem. The program was built successful, but it can't run. It just stopped. I tried to using the "struct" to make a list.I don't know what's wrong with my "insert" function. It's my first time here, hopefully I will get some advices.

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : test2.cpp
// Author      : yan zeng
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================


#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
typedef int BOOLEAN;
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insert(int x, struct Node **pL);

void insert(int x, struct Node **pL){

    if (*pL == NULL) {
        struct Node **pL = (struct Node **) malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

        (**pL).value = x;
        (*pL)->next = NULL;

    }

    else
        insert(x, &((*pL)->next));

}



int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    // insert code here...

    //    make a list by declaring a pointer to a node

    struct Node *NodePointer = NULL;



    for (int i=3; i<20; i+=2) {
        insert(i,&NodePointer);
    }



}
```

Comment: Is it C++ or C you are using? it's a bad behaviour to use `malloc` in C++ anyway.

Comment: What do you mean "it just stopped"? This program produces no output, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: `std::list<int>` not good enough?

Comment: @DeadMG: Since it is homework, I am assuming he needs to implement a list

Comment: if this is c++ homework, at least you have to make it look like c++. this is c

Comment: yeah, I am sorry. This is C..

Comment: @zvrba The program just terminated.

Comment: @hitchbull That's OK since the program doesn't contain any code that would produce some visible side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you is to learn how to use a debugger. Other advice: don't use `malloc/free` in C++, use `new/delete`.

Comment: No, don't use `new/delete`. Use a smart pointer/vector/list class.

Comment: @DeadMG That's a terrible advice for somebody who has not yet understood plain pointers.

Comment: @zvrba: A newcomer to **C++** doesn't **need** pointers until later on. Accelerated C++, by Koenig and Moo doesn't handle pointers until chapter 10.

Comment: thanks for your advice. any link to a good source about debugger?

Comment: @JohannGerell Students usually have no say in how the course is organized, i.e., what they will learn and in which order.

Comment: @hitchbull It depends on the platform (OS).

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few issues in this code, the use of a debugger will definitely help here.

Your program "just stops" because it crashes at

```
(**pL).value = x;
```

I am not sure if this code was provided to you as homework to fix, or if the empty function was provided to you, and you need to fill it out. Either way, that line is wrong.

Also, as others mentioned, you are using `malloc` in a C++ program when you should be using `new`.

Comment: thank you very much.  I think the problem is on this line, but do you mind explaining a little bit more. I was trying to assign a value x to the value pointed by *pL, what's wrong with (**pL).value = x;

Comment: the debugger report "exc_bad_access", which I don't quite understand